# How do I get the correct condition in Firebase Rules?

Tags: firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So I am trying to only allow a client to create a file it it has a certain name, but failing completely doing so.

// This is what I have tried so far:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasAny

```
request.resource.__name__.split('/').hasAny('someDocument')
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#matches

```
request.resource.__name__.matches('.*someDocument')
```

And trying to compare the exact string from the rules-playground

```
request.resource.__name__="/databases/%28default%29/documents/someCollection/someDocument/someOtherCollection/thisDocument"
```

But all of them returned **false** for me.

```
service cloud.firestore 
{
  match /databases/{database}/documents
  {
    match /{document=**}
    {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write: if {insert correct condition here};
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to add a rule for a certain collection? It might be easier to specify rules separately for each collection. If yes, can you please provider a screenshot of your database and explain what you are looking for?

Comment: i want the client to create a file with a specific name in a specific collection.

Comment: Essentially you'll need the collection name and document ID in your condition?

Comment: only the documentID. the example code is only for demonstration

Comment: Have you tried `match /collection/{docId}` in that case? Or you want this rule to be applied to all collections? If yes, then `match /{colId}/{docId}` should work. Unsure if you want this rule to be applied for sub-collections as well .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a wildcard to get the value of a document ID. Try the following:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents { 
    match /collectionName/{docId} {
      allow read, write: if docId.size() > 5; // example 
    } 
  }
}
```

If you want to match collection name as well then you can add another wildcard like this:

```
match /{colId}/{docId}  {  ...  }
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure) for more information.